# Laravel (4.2) form:text issue: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, view

I've got a view in my Laravel app (4.2) that is for editing a database record.

I'm storing two values - colour and heading - as arrays using the form::text method:

```
@foreach($colours as $key => $value)
    {{ Form::label('heading_' . $key,'Heading ' . ($key + 1)) }}                            
    {{ Form::text('heading[]', '', ['id' => 'heading_' . $key, 'class' => 'u-full-width']) }}
    {{ Form::label('colour_' . $key,'Colour ' . ($key + 1)) }}
    {{ Form::text('colour[]', $value, ['id' => 'colour_' . $key, 'class' => 'u-full-width']) }}
@endforeach
```

The initial edit form is fine but if I experience an issue (for example a field being empty) when I return to the original view (through our controller) it throws the following error:

`htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Bizarrely, it works fine for the colour[] fields but seems to be throwing an error for the heading[] fields.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Cheers

Cole

Comment: can you post a `var_dump()` of `$colours`? (obscure any sensitive information)

Comment: also - you say the error occurs when you "`return to the original view`" - is the snippet you've shown from the original view? (ie. is the snippet you've pasted definitely the thing that's throwing the error?)

Comment: The var_dumps for the two offending variables ($heading and $colour):

    `array(6) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(4) "Cash" [2]=> string(18) "Health & Wellbeing" [3]=> string(6) "Wealth" [4]=> string(9) "Lifestyle" [5]=> string(6) "Shared" }` 
    `array(6) { [0]=> string(7) "#999999" [1]=> string(7) "#990099" [2]=> string(7) "#33ccff" [3]=> string(7) "#ffffff" [4]=> string(7) "#000000" [5]=> string(7) "#33ffcc" }`

If I comment out the `{{ Form::text('heading[]' …)}}` from the view then the page/view return fine.

In answer to your question @stef the snippet is from the original view.

Comment: To add some more info, if I reduce the view to {{ Form::text('heading[]') }} it still throws a `htmlentities()` error. However, if I remove this then the view returns as expected. 

The issue seems to be that the view doesn't like showing repeated instances of form::text using an array for the name attribute. However this doesn't explain why the same code works just fine for my colour field.

Comment: To clarify, issues seems to be specifically related to if an array value is empty (I have a required validation rule in my controller)

Comment: hmmm... I can't seem to reproduce this...

Comment: in your example, you aren't using the `$heading` array that you've pasted here

Comment: My first reaction to seeing the question was that one of the `$value`s that you're passing as the second argument to `Form::text` is an array, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can you get the line number in `FormBuilder.php` that calls either `e()` or `htmlentites()`?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given` because the `[]` appended to `heading` and `colour` make them an array in HTML and when `POSTed`.

You're better off doing something like this (in PHP, in your controller, when you submit):

```
$colourArray = [];

foreach(Input::get('colours') as $colour) {
    array_push($colourArray, htmlentities($colour));
}
```

Then you'll have stripped colours in the `$colourArray`.

I haven't actually tested this, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Bizarrely the logic for the colour[] array is working but for the heading[] array is returning this error.

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` colour please?

Comment: I don't think that the logic is actually working for colour[], but is just skipping/ignoring it. Try looping through with the code above and see if it helps.